# How to route all traffic from a specific interface to a specific gateway instead of default route?

Tags: linux, routing, iproute

On my machine I have two interfaces: `wlan0` (default route) and `tun0`.
The `tun0` interface is just a local network, it's ip range is `172.16.150.0/24`, my machine's (machine A) IP address is `172.16.150.1`, and another machine's (machine B) IP address is `172.16.150.128`.
I setup a wifi hotspot and it created for me another interface `ap0`.
I want to route all traffic from the interface `ap0` through the machine B (therefore the gateway should be `172.16.150.128`).

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.179 metric 1024
172.16.150.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.150.1 metric 1024
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.179 metric 1024 
192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.179 metric 1024 
192.168.12.0/24 dev ap0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.12.1
```

At this moment, since the default route is `192.168.0.1`, it routes all traffic to `wlan0` interface to my home router.

I'm not an experienced linux user, so I'm not sure how to make linux kernel route all traffic from `ap0` through `172.16.150.128` gateway, but this is what I tried:

```
$ ip route add default 192.168.12.0/24 via 172.16.150.128
Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "192.168.12.0/24" is a garbage.
```

Here I tried to make kernel route all traffic from `192.168.12.0/24` subnet through the `172.16.150.128` gateway.

```
$ ip route add 192.168.12.0/24 via 172.16.150.128
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

The same as previous command but without the `default` word.
I read somewhere that `ip addr flush dev ap0` might help, but it resets the interface and its ip address, so I need to either restore IP addresses manually via `ip addr add` or restart the wifi hotspot.

I don't think it's the proper way, since I don't want to flush the interface, but instead I want to change the route from `default` to a specific gateway.

How can I do this?

Comment: Policy source-based routing can solve this, but more information is needed. As `tun0` from its name looks like a tunnel interface, it could be related to a tunnel openvpn or else to a VM. Are you sure there's no special remote system involved to establish the tunnel that we should be aware of to not disturb its traffic? Then is the network 172.16.150.0/24 aware of network 192.168.12.0/24? Are there routes in place on systems on that network for this, or should you use (the inferior method of) NAT?

Comment: @A.B, there is no such special system, `tun0` is just a simple interface, I can ping `172.16.50.128`, and I want to use it as a gateway. It seems like the network `172.16.150.0/24` is not aware of `192.168.12.0/24`, but does it need to? I forgot to mention, that I can achieve what I want if I just add `172.16.150.128` as a default interface by `ip route add default via 172.16.150.128`, `ap0` will route through the machine B, but in this scenario all the traffic from my machine is routed through the machine B, but not only the `ap0` interface as I need. I don't think I should use NAT.

Comment: "172.16.150.0/24 is not aware of 192.168.12.0/24, but does it need to?" yes, else they will ignore received packets and/or will never answer back through your system. That's why then NAT is needed. (in addition to policy routing)

Comment: @A.B, but how then it works if the network `172.16.150.128` set as a default gateway? As well as the default gateway via my home router (`192.168.0.1`), is it aware of the network `172.16.150.128`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple routing is not enough here. Simple routing cares about destination. But here the goal is to change route also according to source. Doing this is called [policy routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing). On  Linux this is implemented by using additional selectors (than just the destination) such as source IP address or incoming interface of the source packet to select alternate routing tables. Those alternate routing tables can have other routes, including other default routes, ultimately selecting a different route for the packet than the usual route in the *main* routing table.

This is typically used with a combination of some [`ip rule`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-rule.8#DESCRIPTION) `add ... lookup TABLE` + some `ip route add ...` [`table TABLE`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-route.8#table), with choices tailored to the problem to solve. Usually `ip rule ...` will have selectors based on the source to treat differently, while `ip route ...` will have (and can only have) alternate destinations used for this case.

So for this case one can do like below.

- prepare an alternate routing table (using arbitrary table 1000)

  This table should contain everything needed, so will manually duplicate parts of the main routing table

  ```
  ip route add 192.168.12.0/24 dev ap0 table 1000
  ip route add 172.16.150.0/24 dev tun0 table 1000
  ```

  And of course, to achieve the goal, have the alternate default route too:

  ```
  ip route add default via 172.16.150.128 dev tun0 table 1000
  ```
- select the alternate routing table for the two involved interfaces

  ```
  ip rule add iif ap0 lookup 1000
  ip rule add iif tun0 lookup 1000
  ```

  Routing rules should appear like this:

  ```
  # ip rule
  0:    from all lookup local
  32764:    from all iif tun0 lookup 1000
  32765:    from all iif ap0 lookup 1000
  32766:    from all lookup main
  32767:    from all lookup default
  ```

This solves the routing problem on the machine (but see next part about remote system's routes or using NAT):

- any packet from `ap0` will use the alternate routing table and will be sent to `tun0`

  This includes traffic sent to Internet which will go through 172.16.150.128.
  For the details: traffic sent specifically to this machine, will actually use the *local* routing table first so will still work as usual.
- any packet from `tun0` will use the alternate routing table

  - (if sent to this system, actually the *local* routing table will route it to this system first)
  - if sent to 192.168.12.0/24 it will use `ap0`
  - for the details: in other cases the route lookup would send traffic back to 172.16.150.128

    But this case should never happen in practice.

If `ap0` or `tun0` is ever going down then up, the related route(s) in table 1000 will be lost and will have to be added back.

---

There's one problem left: if systems on the 172.16.150.0/24 LAN don't know anything about 192.168.12.0/24, they will never send back reply traffic to this system (172.16.150.1). They will likely use their own default gateway which is likely 172.16.150.128. Likewise, 172.16.150.128 will likely send any traffic for 192.168.12.0/24 to its own upstream gateway, *away* from this machine, rather than through this machine.

To solve this either:

- make the other systems in 172.16.150.0/24 aware of this LAN (to be preferred)

  Simply adding the route on 172.16.150.128 would be enough: other systems in 172.16.150.0/24 would attempt to send packet through 172.16.150.128 which in addition to routing it through 172.16.150.1 will send ICMP redirect to tell these other systems to send them directly there instead. If that 172.16.150.128 system is also running Linux this should be as simple as:

  ```
  ip route add 192.168.12.0/24 via 172.16.150.1
  ```

  All the systems could also have the very same route added directly. If configured through DHCP, then this setting should be added to the DHCP configuration using DHCP option 121 (or possibly option 249 for older Windows clients)  but that becomes out of scope for this answer.
- or else if previous change can't be done (eg: no control over 172.16.150.128) use NAT

  If it's not possible to set correct routes on systems in 172.16.150.0/24 especially on 172.16.150.128, then one can still collapse all of 192.168.12.0/24 into the reachable 172.16.150.1 using NAT. On the machine add:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.12.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
  ```

  This method allows traffic from 192.168.12.0/24 to 172.16.150.0/24 and through 172.16.150.128 to Internet along the reply packets, but it doesn't allow any service on 192.168.12.0/24 to be reachable from anything else than this machine. Additional NAT settings for specific ports/services are needed to create exceptions.