# How can I configure a podman container to use my wireguard interface only?

Tags: networking, network-interface, wireguard, podman

Using `wg-quick` with the `Table=off` setting, I managed to set up a non-default interface `wg1` on on linux bookworm machine that works as I expect it to:

- `curl ifconfig.co` return my real IP.
- `curl --interface wg1 ifconfig.co` returns my wireguard server's IP.

I am trying to figure out I can now run a rootless podman container that uses `wg1` to communicate with the outside world. By default, podman container use my `eth0` interface; `podman run -it docker.io/curlimages/curl:latest ifconfig.co` returns my real IP, which is what I want. But I cannot find how to do same thing as I did on the host, inside a container.

I thought I could get away with `podman run --network=slirp4netns:outbound_addr=wg1 -it docker.io/curlimages/curl:latest ifconfig.co` but this returns `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ifconfig.co`. It does not seem to be (just?) a DNS issue because using the IP of ifconfig.co instead does not work any better: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.64.110.32 port 80 after 75840 ms: Couldn't connect to server`.

I guess I have a to set up a podman network myself, or a pod, or something like that, but got lost in the many tutorials I found and never managed to get to the result I wanted: `curl`ing through my wireguard server from inside the rootless container.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Using (a convoluted) strace on slirp4netns, I can see that contrary to curl which does setsockopt(... , SO_BINDTODEVICE, ...) slirp4netns just binds to the IP on the interface. That means proper routing has to be in place and that it will affect everything.

Comment: If for example your local WireGuard address is 10.5.0.2 , I guess you'd get a similar result (timeout) by doing `curl --interface 10.5.0.2 172.64.110.32` (which would thus bind to the address instead of the interface just like slirp4netns). I guess slirp4netns could and should be modified to actually bind to the interface rather than to the address on the interface.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Despite my limited understand of networking stuff, I think I arrived to the same conclusion. So there isn't a simple way to get this to work as I intend? There are many tutorials out there, but they all seem awfully complex for what I need. Do you have some pointers maybe?

Comment: You need root access and not use slirp4netns network emulation. An other tool accessible to normal users requiring root to grant rights (to use actual network through a privileged helper) is provided with LXC. I don't know how this can be integrated anywhere else. See: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lxc-user-nic.1.html

Comment: I have root access, rootless sounds better but if it's much easier to achieve with the container running as root it's not that much of an issue to me. This is nothing critical, just my homelab.

Comment: My bad what I intended works with uid, not gid so I'd rather not embark in anything complex. Anyway with what you said, you should just us podman with its default mode: bridge. https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-network-create.1.html#example and see what you can do with this (without WireGuard) so one can ponder what can be done later using WireGuard.

Comment: But the default mode will go via eth0 to communicate with the internet? I'm lost between what route, gateway, etc. I should set. I confess this is all a bit blurry to me :-(

Comment: Here's a Q/A as example to do this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716802/how-to-route-all-traffic-from-a-specific-interface-to-a-specific-gateway-instead . Note that in that Q/A the host will be a router. With slirp4netns network emulation the host is not routing (it emulates routing with host sockets) and this linked Q/A can't apply. With normal networking, the host can be a router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Background

*slirp4netns* is a network emulator that uses sockets instead of routing: from the container's point of view, routing is done by its gateway, but actually the host isn't routing: *slirp4netns* just opens TCP and UDP sockets on the fly for each flow detected coming from the container to handle outgoing traffic.

Using strace on *slirp4netns*, one can see that currently it doesn't do what curl is doing: it doesn't bind to the interface using [`setsockopt(..., SO_BINDTODEVICE, ...)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/socket.7#SO_BINDTODEVICE) but instead binds the socket to the address on the interface. So the route isn't forced to use *wg1*  (`SO_BINDTODEVICE` will also force the use of the interface when there's no route left as if it had added a default route on it. Works without issue for layer 3 interfaces like WireGuard, a bit more problematic for layer 2 interfaces without default route with proper gateway on them) and this fails because there's no route to tell to use *wg1*.

### Wrapper

An [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ld.so.8#LD_PRELOAD) wrapper can be used to work around the lack of the functionality in [libslirp](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/slirp/libslirp). Altering *libslirp*'s [`slirp_bind_outbound()`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/slirp/libslirp/-/blob/v4.7.0/src/misc.c#L426) behavior would have been the better choice, but I chose instead to alter [`bind(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html): frailer but easier to achieve.

The wrapper checks if a bind attempt (made by `slirp4netns`) to the IP address (which must be the address on the target interface) provided as environment variable was made, and in such case in addition also binds the socket to the interface using `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, which is OP's intended behavior, just like the host's *curl* command is doing. Of course should such bind happen for any other reason than `slirp_bind_outbound()`'s invocation then expect disruption.

### Instructions

Requires a minimal development environment with *gcc*. Compile with this command:

```
gcc -o bindtodevicewrapper.so bindtodevicewrapper.c -shared -fPIC -O2 -ldl
```

the file `bindtodevicewrapper.c` below:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <dlfcn.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen) {
    static int init=0;
    static int (*orig_bind)(int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);
    static struct in_addr ipv4bindtodevice;
    static struct in6_addr ipv6bindtodevice;
    static char devname[IFNAMSIZ];

    if (!init) {
        if ((orig_bind=dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"bind")) == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        memset(&ipv4bindtodevice, 0xff, sizeof ipv4bindtodevice);   /* invalid for binding */
        memset(&ipv6bindtodevice, 0xff, sizeof ipv6bindtodevice);   /* invalid for binding */
        if (getenv("WRAPPER_BINDTODEVICE")!=NULL) {
            strncpy(devname, getenv("WRAPPER_BINDTODEVICE"), sizeof devname);
            if(getenv("WRAPPER_INET")!=NULL)
                inet_pton(AF_INET, getenv("WRAPPER_INET"),&ipv4bindtodevice);
            if(getenv("WRAPPER_INET6")!=NULL)
                inet_pton(AF_INET6, getenv("WRAPPER_INET6"),&ipv6bindtodevice);
        }
        init=1;
    }

    if (devname != NULL) {
        if (addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
            if (!memcmp(&((struct sockaddr_in *)addr)->sin_addr, &ipv4bindtodevice, sizeof ipv4bindtodevice))
                setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, devname, strlen(devname)+1);
        }
        else if (addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
            if (!memcmp(&((struct sockaddr_in6 *)addr)->sin6_addr, &ipv6bindtodevice, sizeof ipv6bindtodevice))
                setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, devname, strlen(devname)+1);
        }
    }

    return orig_bind(sockfd, addr, addrlen);
}
```

Requires `jq` to avoid having to guess the IP address on the interface, else one can do it manually for example with `WRAPPER_INET=10.5.0.2` if 10.5.0.2 is the address on *wg1*. This is a single line (with exported variables only for the single command), split with `\` for readability:

```bash
WRAPPER_BINDTODEVICE=wg1 \
WRAPPER_INET=$(ip -4 -json addr show dev wg1 | jq -r '.[].addr_info[0].local') \
LD_PRELOAD=./bindtodevicewrapper.so \
podman run --network=slirp4netns:outbound_addr=wg1 -it docker.io/curlimages/curl:latest ifconfig.co
```

Tested working with IPv4 without DNS (not tested with DNS). Should also work with `WRAPPER_INET6=...` for IPv6 when using *slirp4netns*'s `outbound_addr6` but not tested. No privileged access required.

Comment: WOW. I haven't accepted the answer yet because I haven't tested it but I will. And WOW. Thanks. <3

Comment: It works, thank you, anonymous benevolent network guru-wizard of the internet.